# How to test if an equation is in its simplest (most compact) form

Tags: maxima

I'm building a learning tool where students are required to solve/enter mathematical equations. I'm using maxima to compare the answer of the student with the solution entered by the teacher to determine whether or not the student has solved it correctly. I would like to allow equivalent answers but only if they are in their simplest form. So if the answer is a+(b+1)/2, then a+(1+b)/2, (b+1)/2+a and (1+b)/2+a are also correct, but a+(2b+2)/4 is not.

Is there a way to do this in maxima?

I tried using ratsimp to simplify the expression and then check if it has remained the same, if so it would mean it was already in its simplest form. Unfortunately, if I use this on a+b for instance, it changes the order of the variables to b+a. Is there some way to check if two expressions are identical except for the order of the operations?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in Maxima (I'm a developer fwiw). This is not a simple question to answer; I think it will require some more discussion. My advice is to bring it up on the Maxima mailing list, see: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss By the way, there is at least one active project to use Maxima for generating and evaluating classroom problems, called STACK. I think a web search will find it. There might be other projects like that, I think there's a lot of interest in that concept these days.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I found that you can use the following:
`args(expression), simp: false`

This will return an array of all the arguments, without simplifying, which we then can use to check if this array is the same for two expressions except for the order.